# ISpeechRecognizer.DisplayUI

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I tried to use ISpeechRecognizer.DisplayUI from SAPI 5.4 in C# for bringing the Add Pronunciation UI and it brings the UI but it will be without the given word, which is in this case the word "example".

```
SpSharedRecoContext ssrc = new SpSharedRecoContext();
ISpeechRecognizer ispSpeechReco = ssrc.Recognizer;
ispSpeechReco.DisplayUI(this.Handle.ToInt32(), "Additional Pronunciation", "AddPronunciation", "example");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the typeOfUI is "AddPronunciation", the implementation ignores the extra data parameter.   See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2013/09/12/displayui-and-the-extra-data-parameters.aspx) for details on which typeOfUI parameters support extra data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So does this mean that it would be impossible to get Add Pronunciation UI with the word in it?

Comment: Not through the DisplayUI interface.   AddPronunciation isn't publically documented (it's not found in sapi.h); there's some private communications that go on in WSR to make this happen.